# How can i Select many with contains in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My Product class is

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductColor> ProductColors { get; set; }
}
```

The Color class

```
public class Color
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductColor> ProductColors { get; set; }
}
```

and the intermediate class for creating many to many relationship

```
public class ProductColor
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ColorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Supposing my product model contains

```
ProductID    ProductName
1            Product 1
2            Product 2
3            Product 3
```

My color model contains

```
ColorID  ColorName
1        Red
2        Green
3        Blue
```

And the intermediate model contains

```
ProductID ColorID
1         1
1         2
2         3
```

How can i write a Linq query to get all the colors for each Product in a list?

Comment: You have many-to-many relationship. With EF you do not have to include `ProductColor` entity to your context. Then you won't require any query to get what you want.

Comment: @ieaglle I am really stuck with this. I cannot include the intermediate entity in my context.

Comment: what do you mean? `ProductColor` is your linking entity and it seems to be already added (judging from your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
var res = Products.Select(s => new{ Product = s, Colors = s.ProductColors.Select(m => m.Color) }).ToList();
```

This will produce anonymous type with two properties: `Product` and array of `Color`s that this product has.

Or you can remove `ProductColor` entity, change `Product` to:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

`Color` to:

```
public class Color
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And then you will have already `Product`s with their `Color`s.

Comment: I guess i am doing something terribly wrong, since i get the error... 'Models.Products' does not contain a definition for 'ProductColors' and no extension method 'ProductColors' accepting a first argument of type 'Models.Products' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? It looks that the intermediate table is hidden within the entity framework. Anyway, the problem is solved and your answer is really helpfull.

Comment: I actually solved the issue, please check the answer i posted. I just do not quite understand why the intermediate table is "hidden". I better start reading with the link you posted. Thank you for your effort. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
This is what i was looking for

```
var Colors =  context.Products.SelectMany(p => p.Colors);
```

and filtering by ProductID

```
var Colors =  context.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == 1).SelectMany(p => p.Colors);
```